# c# objects modification: a strange behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, object

I'm developing a WPF C# application and I have a strange behaviour in modification of objects. I try to explain it in general way.
Suppose that you have an object of a class described as follows:

```
public class A
{
  int one;
  bool two;
  List<B> listofBObjects;
}
```

where B is:

```
public class B
{
  int three;
  int four;
}
```

I pass an instance of A class and an instance of B class from a window to another, only defining two variables of type A and B in the second window and passing them before the Show() method, with the following code, executed into an instance of window FirstWindow:

```
SecondWindow newWindow = new SecondWindow();
newWindow.instanceOfA = this.instanceOfA; //instanceOfA is of type A
newWindow.instanceOfB = this.instanceOfA.listOfBObjects[0]; //instanceOfB is of type B
newWindow.Show();
```

If I have to repeat this code twice(that is, opening twice the window), in the first execution everything works as expected, infact if I modify values in `instanceOfB` variable, I see the modification also in `instanceOfA` variable. But, in the second execution, the modification in `instanceOfB` does not affect `instanceOfA`...
The modifications are done in `newWindow`. For example:

```
this.instanceOfB.three++;
this.instanceOfB.four--;
```

Imagine that you are in the FirstWindow. Click on a button and SecondWindow opens, passing both variables as described above. In SecondWindow, do some modifications, click on OK and SecondWindow closes, returning control to FirstWindow. If I reclick on the same button, I reopen SecondWindow. If I do modifications now, they do not affect both variables.

I try to have a look (in VS2012) at both variables in the console with control expression and I see that, in the first pass of code, both variables changes when code above is executed but, in the second pass of code, only `instanceOfB` changes...

EDIT:
Following the code that I use to pass parameters to SecondWindow...types are explaind below

```
 IntermediatePosition obj = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as IntermediatePosition; //IntermediatePosition is Class B
        IntermediatePositionsSettingsWindow ips = new IntermediatePositionsSettingsWindow();
        ips.currentIntermediatePosition = obj;//this is the instanceOfB
        ips.idxOfIpToModify = obj.index;
        ips.currentSingleProperty = this.currentPropertyToShow; //this is the instanceOfA object
        ips.sideIndex = this.sideIndex;
        ips.ShowDialog();
```

Consider that `obj` is given by a button selection into a datagrid, in which each row represents an `IntermediatePosition` object. In the datagrid, there is a column button and, clicking by buttons, `IntermediatePositionsSettingsWindow` is opened with the proper data

EDIT:
I've performed the folloqing check:

```
this.currentPropertyToShow.sides[this.sideIndex].intermediatePositionList[i].Ge‌​tHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode()
```

where `i` is the index of related `IntermediatePosition` object. At first usage of `IntermediatePositionsSettingsWindow` the objects result equals, but in second usage they are different

Why this thing happens? 
If it is needed any other clarification, I will edit the question
Thanks

Comment: Can you should where and how you are trying to modify the variables?

Comment: Yes. I put the description as edit of the question

Comment: Show all the code, with the first modification, and the second where it is misbehaving.

Comment: Why is your code executing twice, is it in a loop?  You need to show the context for this problem.

Comment: The code is not in a loop, but in a window that I open more than once. First time I open the window and do modification into, everything works, but if I reopen the window modifications affects only the instanceOfB variable

Comment: Where are you interrogating the variable.  You're re-instantiating the window each time, so you have a new instance of the window...?

Comment: Yes. Read question editing...I hope is more clear...

Comment: `public class B
        {
            public int a, b;
        }
        public class A
        {
            public int a, b;
            public List<B> c;
            public A()
            {
                c = new List<B>();
                c.Add(new B { a = 2, b = 3 });
            }
        }
A objA = new A();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            objA.c[0].a++;
            objA.c[0].b--;
            Form2 a = new Form2(objA.c[0].a, objA.c[0].b);
            a.Show();
            
        }`

Comment: did u try anything like above comment?

Comment: Do you have a "ToList()" or "ToArray()" somewhere?
This would often cause this sort of behaviour, as it creates new references

Comment: @Nick, there are no ToList() or ToArray()

Comment: @Francesco - You'll need to post ALL the relevant code.  Some of what you've posted won't compile without modification (for example the case on ListOfObjects is different)

Comment: @pm_2 I cannot post all the code of both windows, because it is too much long and difficult to understand. What do you mean by ListofObjects is different?

Comment: C# is case sensitive.  I think you need to create a simplified version of your program, much as Alex has done below and reproduce the problem there.  There are a number of possibilities, for example, you may be inadvertently resetting the variable or the instance.

Comment: @pm_2 it is not possible that, with same code, once is good and once passes in another row in which something is resetted...the code executed is the same each time I open the SecondWindow, so there is not a step of code in which some resetting is done

Comment: @FrancescoDS You **have to** post more code, because right now nobody can answer your question cause it's not reproducible at all.

Comment: @ken2k it is so difficult to do that, because windows are built with a lot of controls and code, so I've tried to simplify the issue in the best way...I don't know if posting all the code of both windows resolves the problem...I try to do my best!

Comment: Have you asserted these relationships? First inside new window, does instanceB.GetHashCode() equal to instanceA.listofBObjects[0].GetHashCode() all the time? Second, trying passing mainwindow's reference to new window and does all four instanceB.GetHashCode() equal to each other all the time? These two asserts you can do by yourself. You should ask the question after you made these asserts.

Comment: `this.currentPropertyToShow` looks suspicious.  Where are you setting it up?

Comment: `this.currentPropertyToShow` is defined in the same page in which it is passed as parameter to `IntermediatePositionsSettingsWindow`. No problem with it.

Comment: @BillZhang is the following comparison the one you suggest? `this.currentPropertyToShow.sides[this.sideIndex].intermediatePositionList[i].GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode()`

Comment: @BillZhang if the comparison is the one suggested, in the first window opening, objects result equals but, in the second usage of window, they results different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give a proper answer to this, as there is insufficient code to correctly work out the issue.  However, if you are databinding, then I believe you need to implement [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.  It is possible that you're issue is simply that you're model is not reflecting the changes to the screen.

Comment: I've verified that changes done on second window are present into the instanceOfB object. The problem is that they do not affect the instanceOfA object, that would contain instanceOfB object...The fact is that on first usage of SecondWindow everything works well...and in between first and second usage nothing changes the objects involved

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem. Here's a simplified representation of your class relation (as I understood from your question). Please let us know if this is correct:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    internal A instanceOfA;
    internal B instanceOfB;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instanceOfB = new B() { };
        instanceOfA = new A() { listOfBObjects = new List<B>() { instanceOfB } };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondWindow newWindow = new SecondWindow();
        newWindow.instanceOfA = this.instanceOfA; //instanceOfA is of type A
        newWindow.instanceOfB = this.instanceOfA.listOfBObjects[0]; //instanceOfB is of type B
        newWindow.Show();
    }
}

public partial class SecondWindow : Window
{

    internal A instanceOfA;
    internal B instanceOfB;
    public SecondWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += SecondWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void SecondWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox
            .Show(String.Format("{0}", 
            this.instanceOfB == this.instanceOfA.listOfBObjects[0]));
        this.instanceOfB.three++;
        this.instanceOfB.four--;
    }
}
```

**Note: this is not an answer, just trying to establish some common ground for further discussions, as comments don't leave you enough freedom for code samples.**

Comment: yes it is something like that. The modifications are not done on Window_Load, but I think that does not change a lot...

Comment: It could change a lot, where are the modifications done exactly?

Comment: In the Window there is a Datagrid linked to a xctk:IntegerUpDown control. When value changes, variables goes ++ or --. So, the modifications are done in the IntegerUpDown_ValueChanged event

Comment: You mean it's databound?  Have you implemented the NotifyChanged event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: @pm_2 no I have not implemented the NotifyChanged

Comment: @FrancescoDS, do you get any `False` messages when you add the `MessageBox` line as in my updated code sample?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I've used [0] index for example, but there is no variables now that stores that index in my code, so I cannot compare the two variables...I must to add the index as variable and try to compare them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pm_2 and @BillZhang comments, I found a row in my code in which `this.currentPropertyToShow`was edited. After the returning back at first window, infact, I perform the refresh of the window, but it is not needed to edit `this.currentPropertyToShow`, so I have commented it and everything works!
Thanks everybody for precious comments and suggestions!